# FastAPI route: Adding dynamic path parameters validation

Tags: python-3.x, validation, server, fastapi

I'm trying to add validation to my route in a fastapi server, followed the instructions [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params-numeric-validations/) and managed to have added validation on my int path parameters like so:

```
route1 = router.get("/start={start:int}/end={end:int}")(route1_func)
```

and my `route1_func`:

```
async def route1_func(request: Request,
                      start: int = Path(..., title="my start", ge=1),
                      end: int = Path(..., title="my end", ge=1)):
    if end <= start:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return True
```

and this works great... but i would like to validate the `end > start` if possible as part of the definition, instead of checking this after going into `route1_func`

is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put path params & query params in a Pydantic class, and add the whole class as a function argument with `= Depends()` after it. The FastAPI docs barely mention this functionality, but it does work.

Then, once you have your args in a Pydantic class, you can easily use Pydantic validators for custom validation.

Here's a rough pass at your use case:

```
class Route1Request(BaseModel):
    start: int = Query(..., title="my start", ge=1)
    end: int = Query(..., title="my end", ge=1)

    @root_validator
    def verify_start_end(cls, vals: dict) -> dict:
        assert vals.get("end", 0) > vals.get("start", 0)
        return vals

@router.get("/")
async def route1(route1_data: Route1Request = Depends()):
    return True
```

*Note: It wasn't clear to me if you meant to use path params or query params. I wrote this example for `Query` params, but it can work with `Path` params with only a few changes.*

Comment: When I try this Pydantic throws a `ValidationError`, but it's _not_ caught by FastAPI and automatically turned into a `RequestValidationError`, so instead of a nice 422 status code with diagnostics I get a plain **Internal Server Error**. The solution seems to be explicitly to `raise RequestValidationError([ErrorWrapper(ex, ("path"))])` in the validator. Does anyone know if this is the correct approach?

Comment: @IanGoldby yes, this is a longstanding problem when using Depends() for query params: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1474 It works fine for request bodies. It looks like you're using the recommended workaround. (I haven't needed this myself.)

Comment: `root_validator` has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can use your validator function as dependency. The function parameters must be the same as in the path

```
def check(start: int, end: int):
    print(start, end)
    if start > end:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='error message')


@router.get('/{start}/{end}', dependencies=[Depends(check)])
async def start_end(
    start: int,
    end: int
):
    return start, end
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Code only is not an answer.